# How to use conditional statements with Java scanner

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use and/or statements in the parameters of `scanner.nextLine().equals(...)`, such as in below

```
scanner.nextLine().equals(x || a) or scanner.nextLine().equals(x && a) ?
```

Thank you

Comment: why not use and test it yourself first and let us know if you feel something strange about the output :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do `||` you can do

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
if (line.equals(x) || line.equals(a)) {
```

The `&&` doesn't make sense unless `x.equals(a)` in which case you can compare it with `x`

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.nextLine()` returns a String so you can do all operations that you can normally do on Strings. However you cannot have, as you said, a parameter for the nextLine function, as in `nextLine(something)`.

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine` does not have parameters, therefore you are not able to execute or on `nextLine`'s parameters. However, `nextLine` returns a `String` and it has an `equals` method, which takes a parameter. Also, Peter Lawrey is right: you wanted to achieve

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
if (line.equals(x) || line.equals(a)) {
```

If you want to simplify it, you can simplify it by creating an array, like this:

```
String[] valuesToCheck = {x, a};
```

and later you can check whether `scanner.nextLine()` matches any of the values:

```
if (valuesToCheck.indexOf(scanner.nextLine()) >= 0) {
    //it matched at least an element
} else {
    //it did not match any element
}
```